# Can't authenticate or authorize with JWT

Tags: spring, jwt, express-jwt

```
public class JWTTokenGeneratorFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if (null != authentication) {
            SecretKey key = Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(SecurityConstants.JWT_KEY.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            String jwt = Jwts.builder().setIssuer("Eazy Bank").setSubject("JWT Token")
                    .claim("username", authentication.getName())
                    .claim("authorities", populateAuthorities(authentication.getAuthorities()))
                    .setIssuedAt(new Date())
                    .setExpiration(new Date((new Date()).getTime() + 30000000))
                    .signWith(key).compact();
            response.setHeader(SecurityConstants.JWT_HEADER, jwt);
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean shouldNotFilter(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return !request.getServletPath().equals("/user");
    }

    private String populateAuthorities(Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> collection) {
        Set<String> authoritiesSet = new HashSet<>();
        for (GrantedAuthority authority : collection) {
            authoritiesSet.add(authority.getAuthority());
        }
        return String.join(",", authoritiesSet);
    }

}
```

This is my jwtgenerator class

```
public class JWTTokenValidatorFilter  extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        String jwt = request.getHeader(SecurityConstants.JWT_HEADER);
        if (null != jwt) {
            try {
                SecretKey key = Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(
                        SecurityConstants.JWT_KEY.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

                Claims claims = Jwts.parserBuilder()
                        .setSigningKey(key)
                        .build()
                        .parseClaimsJws(jwt)
                        .getBody();
                String username = String.valueOf(claims.get("username"));
                String authorities = (String) claims.get("authorities");
                Authentication auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, null,
                        AuthorityUtils.commaSeparatedStringToAuthorityList(authorities));
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new BadCredentialsException("Invalid Token received!");
            }

        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean shouldNotFilter(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return request.getServletPath().equals("/user");
    }

}
```

this is my jwt validator class

Configuration

```
public class ProjectSecurityConfig {

      @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        CsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler requestHandler = new CsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler();
        requestHandler.setCsrfRequestAttributeName("_csrf");
        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
            .cors().configurationSource(new CorsConfigurationSource() {
            @Override
            public CorsConfiguration getCorsConfiguration(HttpServletRequest request) {
                CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
                config.setAllowedOrigins(Collections.singletonList("http://localhost:4200"));
                config.setAllowedMethods(Collections.singletonList("*"));
                config.setAllowCredentials(true);
                config.setAllowedHeaders(Collections.singletonList("*"));
                config.setExposedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Authorization"));
                config.setMaxAge(3600L);
                return config;
            }
                }).and().csrf((csrf) -> csrf.csrfTokenRequestHandler(requestHandler).ignoringRequestMatchers("/contact","/register")
                        .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse()))
                .addFilterAfter(new CsrfCookieFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .addFilterBefore(new RequestValidationBeforeFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .addFilterAt(new AuthoritiesLoggingAtFilter(),BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .addFilterAfter(new AuthoritiesLoggingAfterFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .addFilterAfter(new JWTTokenGeneratorFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .addFilterBefore(new JWTTokenValidatorFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                        .requestMatchers("/myAccount").hasRole("ADMIN")
                        .requestMatchers("/myBalance").hasAnyRole("USER","ADMIN")
                        .requestMatchers("/myLoans").hasRole("USER")
                        .requestMatchers("/myCards").hasRole("USER")
                        .requestMatchers("/user").authenticated()
                        .requestMatchers("/notices","/contact","/register").permitAll()
                .and().formLogin()
                .and().httpBasic();
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

}
```

this is configuration

and this is interface

```
public interface SecurityConstants {

 
    public static final String JWT_KEY = "jxgEQeXHuPq8VdbyYFNkANdudQ53YUn4";
    public static final String JWT_HEADER = "Authorization";
}
```

problem is i cant authorize on my endpoint for example localhost:8080/myAccount?id=1

Comment: *problem is i cant authorize on my endpoint* - what does it mean? Please describe in more detail what problem you have. What are you exactly doing, what result did you expect, and what happened instead? Reading [ask] will also give you some hints.

Comment: whenever i try to log in for example /myAccount endpoint it should return json response, but it does not when i enter my email and pwd it again wants my email and password and does nothing.

Comment: email and pwd i am using has ADMIN authority before i implemented jwt i could authorize without any problem but after changeing things and implemented jwt authorization it is not working anymore.

Comment: Please edit the question to add the information in the question directly.